# Why is image loading at full size even though rendered using next/image?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image, image-optimization

I am rendering [image](https://production-azent-website-cms-uploads.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Banner_2_5d6201ab78.png) with original size 1.4MB (1440 X 600) like this:

```
<Grid item md={9} sm={12}>
    <Box
      position="relative"
      width="100%"
      height="400px"
      overflow="hidden"
     >                  
        <Image
          src={image_url}
          layout="fill"
          objectFit="cover"
          objectPosition="50% 50%"
          quality={60}
        />           
    </Box>
</Grid>

<Grid item md={3} sm={12}>
   ... right side
</Grid>
```

On staging / local env:

- Image served through server: [image_url](https://staging-website.azent.com/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging-azent-website-cms-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com%2FBanner_2_5d6201ab78_c899fcc0f1.png&w=1920&q=60)
- Network tab show resource type as **image/webp** and stats are:

```
On wide-screen (1020px width)
Rendered size:  736 × 352 px
File size:  42.6 kB

On small-screen (600px width)
Rendered size:  568 × 304 px
File size:  37.6 kB
```

On production env:

- Image served through server: [image_url](https://azent.com/_next/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Fproduction-azent-website-cms-uploads.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com%2FBanner_2_5d6201ab78.png&w=1920&q=60)
- Network tab show resource type as **image/png** and stats are:

```
On wide-screen (1020px width)
File size:  1.4 MB

On small-screen (600px width)
File size:  1.2 MB
```

What is causing this behaviour? Why is image optimization not working on production?

I am using Next 10.0.5 and the website is deployed on AWS. Let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: Could you link to the page in production that uses this image, please?

Comment: Can you also show us your `next.config.js` file?

Comment: Figured out this post: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21701, will update after implementing solutions mentioned here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was CDN was not forwarding the Accept header to the origin (NextJS).

As mentioned in this [answer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21701#issuecomment-797842257)  "NextJS decides whether to serve the image as webP vs jpg/png/svg etc. depending on the Accept header. With the current settings, CDN would not forward the Accept header to the origin"